# Creating instances of all subclasses in Python

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a superclass with several subclasses. Each subclass overrides the "solve" method with some a different algorithm for estimating the solution to a particular problem. I'd like to efficiently create an instance of each subclass, store those instances in a list, and then take the sum (or average) of the estimates that the subclasses give:

```
class Technique():

    def __init__(self):
        self.weight = 1

    def solve(self, problem):
        pass

class Technique1(Technique):

    def __init__(self):
        super()

    def solve(self,problem):
        return 1

class Technique2(Technique):

    def __init__(self):
        super()

    def solve(self,problem):
        return 6

 class Technique3(Technique):

    def __init__(self):
        super()

    def solve(self,problem):
        return -13

testCase = 3
myTechniques = []
t1 = Technique1()
myTechniques.append(t1)
t2 = Technique1()
myTechniques.append(t2)
t3 = Technique1()
myTechniques.append(t3)

print(sum([t.solve(testCase) for t in myTechniques])
```

The code at the end feels very clunky, particularly as the number of subclasses increases. Is there a way to more efficiently create all of the instances?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might try this:

```
myTechniques = [cls() for cls in Technique.__subclasses__()]
```

Note that it does *not* return indirect subclasses, only immediate ones. You might also consider what happens if some subclass of `Technique` is itself abstract. Speaking of which, you should be using `ABCMeta` and `abstractmethod`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: If this question were asked again today, I'd suggest `__init_subclass__` as the cleanest answer.